# Move UITextField when keyboard opens in a chat style window that uses TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I've previously gotten this to work in a message chat window that uses Collection View, but when using TableView, I have been unable to make the textview appear above the keyboard using the same code. If I change the bottomConstraint to a value that is outside of the TableView, well above the top, it will appear fine... It's like the table blocks/is in front of my textfield (also can't see a z-index?).

At the moment, I am now implementing a version that moves the whole view up instead, along with the tableview and messages, but I need them to still be visible too. After searching for longer than I should admit and through much frustration, I am unable to find a solution that fits my scenario which seems odd, and makes me think I'm severely missing something. 
If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be much appreciative!

Both versions of my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// Code that moves the view - works but moves tableview messages off screen
    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {

        guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {return}

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height
        }
        else {
            view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }

// Old code that only works on Collection View
    @objc private func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = (notification as Notification).userInfo, let value = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }

    if ((userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue) != nil {
        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
        var newHeight: CGFloat
        if isKeyboardShowing {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                bottomConstraint.constant = newHeight
            }
        }
        else {
            newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height
            bottomConstraint?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + messageInputContainerView.bounds.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I am not that much into Swift and it is unclear to me what you mean with ".., but I need them to still be visible too", I followed the same approach you describe in an objective-C based app. However, I did not move the entire view, but only the tableview. In Swift probaby something like:
    
    `tableView.frame.origin.y -= -keyboardRect.height`

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I can see with a little bit of fiddling how this could also work. I can't vote your comment up as yet with my low score though, so I wish you many good things for your help :) 
I have found the issue with my transposing my collectionView code and managed to get the textfield to display in front of the tableView so I have reverted back to that code. Thanks again for the tip :)